# API vs REST API

Tags: api

The acronym "API" is used in many contexts. I see it mostly in the context "REST API" these days.

I was confused to see it in contexts like "Node API" or "Java API" or "Django API" or "Python API".

The use-case "RESTful API" makes a lot of sense to me. But why "Python API" instead of "Docu Python Std.lib"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) means "application programming interface" and applies to anything that have an programming interface like Java, .NET etc.

Why do you think it makes only sense for REST and not for the rest?

Comment: I can see that a web service has an interface that I can interact with. But where is the interface in a library of modules in Node? I can import them and use them. But where is the interaction with it? // Also if I google API I'll get "REST API" or "Webservice API" mostly. Almost never will I get "Python API" as a search result.

Comment: I'm no node.js expert but if you want to "talk" with node.js you also have to follow the interfaces that node provides. For example how to write to the console https://nodejs.org/api/console.html is also an interface (API).